# Turn Off Scrollable feature of Listview.builder

Tags: dart, material-design, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I want to use ListView.builder because of its itemBuilder feature. But I want to turn the scrollable feature off as it makes my app hard to use, as I end up scrolling only the widgets made using ListView.builder, instead of the entire screen. Thus, only a certain widget of screen scrolls, instead of the complete screen, making it a bad user experience.

Comment: I got the solution, I defined the ScrollPhysics for the ListView.builder, using ` physics: ScrollPhysics(parent: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics())`, I will let this question be on StackOverflow, in case someone finds himself in the same situation.

Comment: You answered to the question concerning the deactivation of the `ListView` scrolling feature. But to deep further, you are maybe in a situation where a `CustomScrollView`, a `SliverList`, and `SliverToBoxAdapter`s would be a good fit.

Comment: @Letsar Would those allow me to use a item builder function?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to create a `SliverChildBuilderDelegate` and pass it to the `SliverList` constructor.

Comment: I haven't used Sliver's before, and am hesitant to use them as I don't know the behavior. Any suggested resources from where I can learn about them and look at sample implementations to get a good grasp.

Comment: I've found the official documentation pretty good. You can take a look at the example in https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html. I encourage you to deep further, and ask questions on StackOverflow, if you want an deeper explanation for some concepts.

Comment: Great! I will go look at this.

Answer (score 6):

`physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` use this in the listview builder. The listview builder will not scroll